# Update YAML file with external input in json format in yq

Tags: json, parsing, formatting, yaml, yq

I have a file in.yaml with the content

```
name: test
```

I want to create dynamically content of an array in a yaml file. I am using yq and an json encoding of the element to be added, but when I provide the content as a string the elements are not appended.

Consider the code:

```
entry='[{"name":"mango","color":"yellow"}]'

ENTRY=$entry yq e '."details"=strenv(ENTRY)' in.yaml
```

Output:

```
name: test
details: '[{"name":"mango","color":"yellow"}]'
```

The following works, but does not make me pass the entry via an other attribute.

```
yq e '."details"=[{"name":"mango","color":"yellow"}]' in.yaml
```

Output:

```
name: test
details:
  - name: mango
    color: yellow
  - name: apple
    color: red
```

I am using this incorrect or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0):

As `strenv` converts the variable's contents into a literal string, use `from_json` to decode it again. Then, reset the quoting style to empty (in both, keys and values) using `... style=""` in order to match your desired output style:

```bash
ENTRY="$entry" yq e '.details=(strenv(ENTRY) | from_json | ... style="")' in.yaml
```

Alternatively, avoid the initial conversion in the first place by changing `strenv` to just `env`, so the input can be directly interpreted as YAML (JSON is a subset of YAML). You'd still need to reset the quoting style, though:

```bash
ENTRY="$entry" yq e '.details=(env(ENTRY) | ... style="")' in.yaml
```